# Lisp: Problem with package prefix in macro/function definitions

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I want to create a macro (or function) which will contain package-prefixed symbols. This is possible only if those packages have already been defined. Why? As long as i have defined the packages by the time the macro/function gets called, why is there a problem if they are undefined when the macro/function is defined?

The reason I want this is that i want to have convenience functions in my init file for starting-stopping stuff i develop in different projects-packages but I dont want to load all the projects just to be able to define the convenience functions, since i only develop one project at a time.

Comment: Maybe you should give an example what you want to do and we can tell you how to solve it. A symbol needs to be in a defined package or in no package. There are some advanced options what one could do, but it makes only sense to tell you about it, when we know your use case.

Comment: I added in the question the reason why i need this.

Comment: Now here is a case where I think the accepted answer should be shared evenly between Xach and Rainer. Xach answered to the first half, which was the whole question inittially, then Rainer helped me find a solution to the source of the problem. So, I am tossing a coin :P

Comment: As if Rainer needs the points!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The source code is read by the Lisp reader before evaluation (see [read](http://l1sp.org/cl/read)). The reader can't intern the symbols if the packages aren't already defined.

Comment: Is there any way I can have this functionality? Somehow delay the interning of prefixed symbols until the packages have been define? The reason for all this is that i want to have convenience functions in my init file for starting-stopping stuff i develop in different packages but I dont want to load all the projects just to be able to define the convenience functions, since i only develop one project at a time...

Comment: @paralife: see my other answer

Comment: One option: don't define those convenience functions in your init file, define them in new projects that have a dependency on the main thing, e.g. paralife-hunchentoot could be a project with your start/stop functions in it that depends on hunchentoot.

Comment: @paralife: The interning of a symbol (typically) happens at read-time, when teh symbol is converted from 'external representation' to a symbol. If the package you say a symbol belongs to doesn't exist, it cannot be interned. Rainer's code (using FIND-SYMBOL) delays the finding of the symbol until run-time and for the specific purpose of seldom-run, performance-uncritical convenience functions, that is perfectly sensible, but should probably not be used in a tight inner loop.

Answer (score 3):

```
(funcall (find-symbol "RENDER-SUPER-FANCY-GRAPHICS"
                      "THIS-PACKAGE-DOES-NOT-YET-EXIST")
         *standard-output* :width 1000 :height 800)
```

Comment: you mean to put your template in a macro?